# Universal link multiple domains

Tags: ios, appcelerator, ios-universal-links

Can iOS app have more than 1 universal link domain?

I've added both domains into the Entitlements file, but only 1 domain seems to work.

E.g. 
`https://subdomain.domain1.com/link`     - this works
`https://subdomain.domain2.com/link`     - this doesn't work

However domain 2 is an alias site for domain 1. So the association file is the same on both.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there any output in your device's log?  You may run into issues accessing the apple-app-site-association file if domain 2 is an alias - I believe Apple requires this file be accessed directly.

Comment: I'll check the device log. But the apple-app-site-association file is available in both obviously. Thanks

Comment: The log says:  Oct 12 20:14:33 iPad-Air assertiond[63] <Error>: assertion failed: 13G36: assertiond + 30600 [0B862A7D-6E8B-3778-AD17-C7694ECD5BCD]: 0x16
Oct 12 20:14:33 iPad-Air Unknown[63] <Error>: 
Oct 12 20:14:33 iPad-Air swcd[356] <Notice>: 2016-10-12 08:14:33.178461 PM [SWC] Immediate retry for domain 'subdomain.domain2.com'
Oct 12 20:14:33 iPad-Air swcd[356] <Notice>: 2016-10-12 08:14:33.593025 PM [SWC] Immediate retry for domain 'subdomain.domain2.com'
Oct 12 20:14:35 Pad-Air backboardd[56] <Warning>: |GAXGeneral|info| Updating session app bundle ID to com.apple.mobilesafari.

Comment: From [SWC] Immediate retry for domain 'subdomain.domain2.com' it sounds like indeed there is an issue, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

An iOS app can absolutely have multiple Universal Links domains. However, Apple is extremely strict about enforcing the no redirects rule on `apple-app-site-association` files. Without seeing the actual domains, we can't do much troubleshooting for you, but generally anything other than a CNAME for aliasing may cause issues.

It's also possible you inadvertently disabled Universal Links on the second domain. If you paste a link into the Notes app and long-press on it, do you get an **Open in [App Name]** option?

Comment: ingelby.aftersalesdashboard.com ingelby.vehicleaftersales.com The first one works, the second does not.

Comment: Both domains are using A records in DNS, so there shouldn't be an issue with redirects. If you remove ingelby.aftersalesdashboard.com from your entitlements and use only ingelby.vehicleaftersales.com, does the latter work then?

Comment: I tried removing the working one and just having ingelby.vehicleaftersales.com and it didn't work. Frustrating!

Comment: Indeed! Did you check to ensure you haven't accidentally disabled the links (see the note at the end of my answer)? Can you try testing on another device? I can't think of anything else that would be causing this now...

Answer (score 0):

Though your curl works it sounds like you are using a redirect, which is one of the limitations as [described by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html):

> The file needs to be accessible via HTTPS—without any redirects—at https:///apple-app-site-association or https:///.well-known/apple-app-site-association

I believe you will have to host the second domain individually for Universal Links to work.

Comment: Here are the domains to try:

Comment: https://ingelby.aftersalesdashboard.com/
https://ingelby.vehicleaftersales.com/

The first one works, the second does not

Comment: I'm not sure how Apple assesses the redirect but like I said if you're using a redirect it will cause problems - I'm not surprised it doesn't work.

Comment: no there's no redirect, it's simply an alias site in apache

Comment: I don't think you can use aliases - you could write a new question because your concern is regarding alias sites, not as much multiple domains